# 68k assembly - plus symbol on address registers

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, 68000, addressing-mode

While reverse engineering something for fun, I came across the following piece of assembly:

```
move.b  (a1)+,(a0)+
```

I understand that the parentheses mean 'value of', but what does the plus symbol stand for? How would I accurately translate this to C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(a1)+` accesses memory at `a1` and increments `a1` by the size of the operation. In this case 1. What you have looks like a part of a typical loop that copies memory.

Comment: Ahhh.. that makes so much sense... then beneath is a 'bne.s'. Which I suppose means it will continue until it finds a \0... Thanks! I'll accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 6):

The parentheses mean indirect addressing and the `+` means post-increment. In this case both `a1` and `a0` will be increased by the size of the operation after the instruction is executed. Another common addressing mode is indirect addressing with pre-decrement, `-(An)`.

The typical use for a `move` instruction where indirect addressing with post-increment is used for both the source and destination register is to copy data from one memory location to another in a loop.

The [Programmer's Reference Manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/M68000PM.pdf) is invaluable for any M68000 programmer.

In C, `*a0++ = *a1++;` for `char *a0, *a1` variables. The loop body for a classic simplistic memcpy going only 1 byte at a time.  (For larger copies, you'd prefer `move.w` or `move.l`, or a more optimized memcpy implementation.)